Unable to override endpoints.s3 on terraform init
I would like to override aws backend configuration on terraform init, using Azure DevOps powershell task but got syntax error for s3 endpoint config
It used to work like this:
- pwsh: |
    terraform init -backend=true -force-copy -get=true -input=false -backend-config='endpoints={s3="$(S3_ENDPOINT)"}' -backend-config="bucket=$(S3_BUCKET)" -backend-config="key=$(S3_KEY)" -backend-config="region=$(S3_REGION)" -backend-config="access_key=$(OVH_ACCESS_KEY)" -backend-config="secret_key=$(OVH_SECRET_KEY)"
  name: tf_init
  displayName: 'Terraform : init'
  workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/${{ parameters.root_directory }}'

Where $(S3_ENDPOINT) = "https://s3.gra.io.cloud.ovh.net/"
Got this error:

Initializing the backend...
╷
│ Error: Missing attribute separator
│
│   on -backend-config="endpoints={s3=https://s3.gra.io.cloud.ovh.net/}" line 1:
│   (source code not available)
│
│ Expected a newline or comma to mark the beginning of the next attribute.


As per the link, and your same command in working pipeline, try to add same backend values for a check.

Suggest to follow the sample in bash task for a check, or try below sample from @ruiJarimba, let me know if you have any queries.

As per Credentials and Shared Configuration:

We recommend using environment variables to supply credentials and other sensitive data. If you use -backend-config or hardcode these values directly in your configuration, Terraform will include these values in both the .terraform subdirectory and in plan files.

So I'd suggest you to rewrite your task like this:
- pwsh: |
    terraform init -backend=true -force-copy -get=true -input=false -backend-config="bucket=$(S3_BUCKET)" -backend-config="key=$(S3_KEY)" 
  name: tf_init
  displayName: 'Terraform : init'
  workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/${{ parameters.root_directory }}'
  env:
    AWS_S3_ENDPOINT: $(S3_ENDPOINT)
    AWS_REGION: $(S3_REGION)
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $(OVH_ACCESS_KEY)
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $(OVH_SECRET_KEY)

Note:

This is untested code, so please double-check in the documentation what is the right environment variable for each setting
Not sure if it is possible to override bucket and key using environment variables

